# ReactJS: Select Input sometimes updates & sometimes not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have form to edit/update "Survey" data. In the form I have bunch of select elements which creating the problem for me.I select a survey to edit from the datatable page of my app. Which passes the survey object to the edit page which contains the id of that survey which I use to fetch the whole data of that survey for edit and & display that data in my form.

In the edit page I have to call two API to fetch some data. 1) to get the whole survey data based on the survey id 2) the survey metadata which is nothing the the options I want to give in the  element.So I call them one after another & they are asynchronous.

For example survey metadata will contain one array called `survey_types` which will have two options `Pre Insurance` & `Post Loss`, So i will display them in the  input in my form. survey_types example data,

```
"survey_types": [
            {
                "1": "Pre Insurance"
            },
            {
                "2": "Post Loss"
            }
        ],
```

But I have to show one them as selected already based on the survey data I get,But my survey object which i get from API will look like this,

```
survey {
  "survey_type": "Post Loss",
  // some other values as well
}
```

Now when I submit my form I will send the `survey_type` as "Post Loss" which server won't accept as it requires the corresponding integer value of that option.
So correct the selected values in the  element I wrote one method called `_setProperValForMetaDataSelect` which will change the state of `survey_type` value from `Post Loss` to `1`.

**So the problem is that when my method runs sometimes I see the value selected in the  elements and sometimes it wipes off the selected value of  and shows default value as '--select--'**

I am also using the Redux to maintain some global state as well.
Here is my whole code of the form, I have removed some other input fields to make it shorter
import React from "react";

```
import Formsy from "formsy-react";
import {
    Row,
    Col,
    Button,
    FormGroup,
    Label,
    Input,
    Spinner,
} from 'reactstrap';


import Widget from "../../components/Widget";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import '../../../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
import { getSurvey, getSurveyMetadata, updateSurvey } from '../../services/api/surveys'

import { Formik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { showConfirmDialog } from "../../components/utils/dialogs";


class EditSurvey extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            surveyUid: '',
            surveyMeta: {
                survey_types: [],
                survey_subtypes: [],
                transit_types: [],
                currencies: [],
                live_survey_types: []
            },
            survey: {
                user: this.props.user ? this.props.survey.user : '',
                amount_paid: this.props.survey ? this.props.survey.amount_paid : '',
                currency: this.props.survey ? this.props.survey.currency : '',
                survey_type: this.props.survey ? this.props.survey.survey_type : '',
                survey_subtype: this.props.survey ? this.props.survey.survey_subtype : '',
                transit_type: this.props.survey ? this.props.survey.transit_type : '',
            }
        }

    }



    componentDidMount() {
        
        let survey = this.props.location.state
        // get whole data fo survey to edit
        if (survey) {
            this.setState({ surveyUid: survey.uid })
            this.props.dispatch(getSurvey(survey.uid))
        }

        getSurveyMetadata((data) => {
            this.setState({ surveyMeta: data },this._setProperValForMetaDataSelect)
        })
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({ survey: nextProps.survey },this._setProperValForMetaDataSelect)
    }

    
    _setProperValForMetaDataSelect() {
        
        if (this.props.isSurveyLoading && this.state.surveyMeta.length == 0) {
            return
        }

        const { survey_types, survey_subtypes, transit_types, currencies, live_survey_types } = this.state.surveyMeta

        const { currency, survey_type, survey_subtype, transit_type, live_survey_type } = this.state.survey || {}

        let _currency = ''
        let _survey_type = ''
        let _survey_subtype = ''
        let _transit_type = ''
        let _live_survey_type = ''

        currencies.forEach((item) => {
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {

                if (key == currency) {
                    _currency = value
                }
            }
        })

        survey_types.forEach((item) => {
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
                if (key == survey_type) {
                    _survey_type = value
                }
            }
        })

        transit_types.forEach((item) => {
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
                if (key == transit_type) {
                    _transit_type = value
                }
            }
        })

        survey_subtypes.forEach((item) => {
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
                if (key == survey_subtype) {
                    _survey_subtype = value
                }
            }
        })

        live_survey_types.forEach((item) => {
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
                if (key == live_survey_type) {
                    _live_survey_type = value
                }
            }
        })

        let updatedValues = {
            currency: _currency || currency,
            survey_type: _survey_type || survey_type,
            survey_subtype: _survey_subtype || survey_subtype,
            transit_type: _transit_type || transit_type,
            live_survey_type: _live_survey_type || live_survey_type
        }
        
        this.setState({
            survey: {
                ...this.state.survey,
                ...updatedValues
            }

        },()=>console.log('After updated',this.state.survey))

    }


    handleFormSubmit = async (data) => {

        data['uid'] = this.state.surveyUid

        let confirmed = await showConfirmDialog()

        if (confirmed) {
            this.props.dispatch(updateSurvey(data))
        }

    };

    _generateSelectElement(name, onChange, onBlur, options, selectedValue = null) {
        /**
         * Use to construct the <select> ele for survey metadata.
         * Each metadata may have any number of key/value pairs,
         * need to dynamically get those key & value for option elements
         */

        let defaultValue = ''
        if(selectedValue){
            options.forEach((item)=>{
                for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
                    if(selectedValue == value || selectedValue == key){
                        defaultValue = value
                    }
                }
                
            })
        }

        return <Input
            name={name}
            type='select'
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChange={onChange}
            defaultValue={defaultValue}
        >
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            {options ? options.map((item) => {
                // using this to dynamically seperate the key & value of the object
                for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
                    return <option key={value} value={value}>{key}</option>
                }
            }) : null}
        </Input>



    }

    render() {
        const { survey_types, survey_subtypes, transit_types, currencies, live_survey_types } = this.state.surveyMeta

        const surveySchema = Yup.object().shape({
            user: Yup.string()
                .required('This field is required.'),

            amount_paid: Yup.number()
                .typeError('Enter a valid amount.')
                .positive('Amount value cannot be negative.'),

            currency: Yup.string()
                .required('This field is required.'),

            survey_type: Yup.string()
                .required('This field is required.'),

            survey_subtype: Yup.string()
                .required('This field is required.'),

            transit_type: Yup.string()
                .required('This field is required.'),

        });


        if (this.props.isSurveyLoading) {
            return <center><Spinner color='primary' /></center>
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={12}>
                        <Widget
                            title={
                                <p style={{ fontWeight: 700 }}>
                                    Edit Survey
                                </p>
                            }
                        >
                            <Formik
                                enableReinitialize
                                initialValues={{ ...this.state.survey }}
                                validationSchema={surveySchema}
                                onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
                            >
                                {({
                                    values,
                                    errors,
                                    touched,
                                    handleChange,
                                    handleBlur,
                                    handleSubmit,
                                    isSubmitting,
                                    /* and other goodies */
                                }) => (
                                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                        <Row>
                                            <Col lg={6} md={6}>

                                                <FormGroup>
                                                    <Label for="user">
                                                        Owner
                                                    </Label>
                                                    <Input
                                                        type="text"
                                                        name="user"
                                                        placeholder="Enter owner"
                                                        value={values.user || ''}
                                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                                                    />
                                                    {errors.user && touched.user ? (
                                                        <small className='text-danger'>{errors.user}</small>
                                                    ) : null}
                                                </FormGroup>

                                                <FormGroup>
                                                    <Label for="survey_subtype">
                                                        Survey Sub-Type
                                                    </Label>
                                                    { this._generateSelectElement('survey_subtype',handleChange,handleBlur,survey_subtypes,values.survey_subtype) }
                                                    {errors.survey_subtype && touched.survey_subtype ? (
                                                        <small className='text-danger'>{errors.survey_subtype}</small>
                                                    ) : null}
                                                </FormGroup>

                                                <FormGroup>
                                                    <Label for="currency">
                                                        Currency
                                                    </Label>
                                                    { this._generateSelectElement('currency',handleChange,handleBlur,currencies,values.currency) }
                                                    {errors.currency && touched.currency ? (
                                                        <small className='text-danger'>{errors.currency, values.currency}</small>
                                                    ) : null}
                                                </FormGroup>

                                                

                                                <FormGroup>
                                                    <Label for="live_survey_type">
                                                        Live Survey Type
                                                    </Label>
                                                    
                                                    { this._generateSelectElement('live_survey_type',handleChange,handleChange,live_survey_types,values.live_survey_type) }

                                                    {errors.live_survey_type && touched.live_survey_type ? (
                                                        <small className='text-danger'>{errors.live_survey_type}</small>
                                                    ) : null}
                                                </FormGroup>

                                               
                                               

                                                <br />


                                                <FormGroup>
                                                    {this.props.isFetching ?
                                                        <Spinner color='primary' /> :
                                                        <>
                                                            <Button color="warning"
                                                                type="submit"
                                                                className="mr-xs"
                                                                disabled={this.props.isFetching}
                                                            >
                                                                UPDATE
                                                            </Button>
                                                            <Button color="default">Cancel</Button>
                                                        </>
                                                    }

                                                </FormGroup>


                                            </Col>

                                            <Col lg={6} md={6}>

                                                <FormGroup>
                                                    <Label for="survey_type">
                                                        Survey Type
                                                    </Label>
                                                    { this._generateSelectElement('survey_type',handleChange,handleBlur,survey_types,values.survey_type) }
                                                    {errors.survey_type && touched.survey_type ? (
                                                        <small className='text-danger'>{errors.survey_type}</small>
                                                    ) : null}
                                                </FormGroup>


                                                <FormGroup>
                                                    <Label for="transit_type">
                                                        Transit Type
                                                    </Label>
                                                    { this._generateSelectElement('transit_type',handleChange,handleBlur,transit_types,values.transit_type) }
                                                    {errors.transit_type && touched.transit_type ? (
                                                        <small className='text-danger'>{errors.transit_type}</small>
                                                    ) : null}
                                                </FormGroup>


                                            </Col>

                                        </Row>
                                    </form>
                                )}
                            </Formik>
                        </Widget>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div >
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        isSurveyLoading: state.surveys.isSurveyLoading,
        isFetching: state.surveys.isFetching,
        survey: state.surveys.selected
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditSurvey);
```

Comment: Put your example into a codesandbox and simplify your problem for explanation. This is too large.

Comment: I know it is,I will try but I am not sure I will be able to create codesandbox as my code have other custom components,apis, redux it will take more time than debugging.